# Question about $C^2$ functional

Tags: functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations

i have this problem :
[image]

The solutions of P correspond to critical points of the fuctional

$$\phi(x)=\frac12 \int_0^{2\pi} |x'|^2 dt - \int_0^{2\pi} F(t,x) dt , x\in E $$

where $F(t,x)=\int_0^x f(t,s) ds$ and $E$ is the Hilbert space $$E=\lbrace x\in L^2([0,2\pi],\mathbb{R}),x'\in L^2([0,2\pi],\mathbb{R}]), x(0)=x(2\pi)\rbrace$$

My question is how to prove that $\phi$ is $C^2$ ?

Please

Thank you

Comment: Do you know how to take the derivative of $\phi$? Or, more generally, do you know how to compute the [Frechet derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative)?

Comment: Yes, we find : $\phi'(x).y=\int_0^{2\pi} x'y'dt-\int_0^{2\pi} f(t,x) ydt$ ,$\phi''(x)y.z=\int_0^{2\pi} y'z'dt-\int_0^{2\pi} f'(t,x) y z dt$

Comment: Then all you need is to apply the definition of continuity: you need to show that at every $x$, for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that if $|x - \tilde{x}|_E < \delta$, you have that $\| \phi'(x) - \phi'(\tilde{x})\| < \epsilon$ and $\|\phi''(x) - \phi''(\tilde{x})\| < \epsilon$ where the norms are the appropriate operator norms.

Comment: ||\phi'(x_1)-\phi'(x_2)||\leq \int_0^{2\pi} (x_1'-x_2')y' dt+\int_0^{2\pi} |f(t,x_1)-f(t,x_2)|dt$ right ?

Comment: Not quite. There shouldn't be a $y'$ in the right hand side, and by the definition of the operator norm $\|A\| = \sup_{|y| = 1} |Ay|$ you should, for example, estimate $$ \left|\int_0^{2\pi} (x_1' - x_2') y' \mathrm{d}t\right| \leq |x_1 - x_2|_E |y|_E = |x_1 - x_2|_E$$ where we used Cauchy-Schwarz

Comment: The $f'$ term can be a bit tricky: you need to use uniform continuity of $f'$ on compact intervals and that by Sobolev's inequality (or fundamental theorem of calculus) the $E$ norm of $x$ controls the $C^0$ norm of $x$.

Comment: Ok, 1) $\int_0^{2\pi} |f(t,x_1)-f(t,x_2)| dt\leq 4\pi \sup_{x \in [0,2\pi]}|f(t,x)|$ ? 2) we don't have the unifor continuity of f'? please, thank you

Comment: (1) no. Remember, you need a factor of $\epsilon$ from somewhere. (Use differentiability to get Lipschitz continuity!). (2) I assume that $f$ is $C^1$ (which your quoted source seems to assume too). Continuous functions are uniformly continuous on any compact domain. Think through your arguments slowly: the first one that comes to mind isn't necessary the right one. I don't have the time this afternoon to write it up for you. If you haven't figured it out by tomorrow, ping me (with `@Willie` in your comment) and I'll write something up.

Comment: @WillieWong i dont know how to complete the prove >_< ,please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with, we first show that $x\in E$ is bounded almost everywhere. Since $x'\in L^2([0,2\pi])$ we have that using Cauchy-Schwarz

$$ \int_0^{2\pi} |x'| \mathrm{d}t \leq \sqrt{2\pi} \left(\int_0^{2\pi} |x'|^2 \mathrm{d}t\right)^{\frac12} $$

or that $x'$ is in $L^1$, hence $x$ is absolutely continuous. Integrating directly we have that

$$\sup_{t\in[0,2\pi]}x(t) - \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} x~\mathrm{d}t \leq \sup_{t\in [0,2\pi]} x(t) - \inf_{t\in [0,2\pi]} x(t) \leq \int_0^{2\pi}|x'| ~\mathrm{d}t $$

(The first inequality follows from the fact that the average of $x$ is greater than its infimum.) This implies (by considering also the difference of the infimum to the mean)

$$ \sup_{t\in [0,2\pi]} |x(t)| \leq \sqrt{2\pi} \|x'\|_{L^2} + \sqrt{2\pi} \|x\|_{L^2} $$

the second term on the RHS coming from estimating the mean of $x$ using Cauchy-Schwarz again. Hence we have that

$$ |x(t)| \leq \sqrt{2\pi} \|x\|_E $$

Okay, first let us show that the mapping is $C^1$. You have computed

$$ \phi'(x)\cdot y = \int_0^{2\pi} x' y' - f(t,x) y~ \mathrm{d}t $$

So fixing an $x$, and let $\|\tilde{x} - x\|_E < \delta < 1$, we have

$$ | \phi'(x)\cdot y - \phi'(\tilde{x})\cdot y| \leq \int_0^{2\pi} \big|(x' - \tilde{x}')y'\big| + \big|[f(t,x) - f(t,\tilde{x})]y\big| ~\mathrm{d}t $$

The first term on the LHS we estimate by Cauchy-Schwarz, and it is bounded by $\delta \|y\|_E$. To estimate the second term, we use that $f$ is continuous. Since both $x$ and $\tilde{x}$ verify $\|x\|_E, \|\tilde{x}\|_E < \|x\|_E + \delta < \|x\|_E + 1$, we have that

$$ |x(t)|, |\tilde{x}(t)| < \sqrt{2\pi} (\|x\|_E + 1) $$

Note that the RHS is a constant, since we have already chosen a fixed $x$. This means that it suffices to consider $f$ on the subdomain $[0,2\pi]\times [- \sqrt{2\pi}(\|x\|_E + 1), \sqrt{2\pi}(\|x\|_E + 1)]$, which is compact. Hence $f$ is uniformly continuous.

We note that

$$ |x(t) - \tilde{x}(t)| < \sqrt{2\pi} \|x - \tilde{x}_E \leq \sqrt{2\pi}\delta $$

Now, let $\epsilon > 0$. By uniform continuity of $f$ on the subdomain, we can choose $\delta < \frac12 \epsilon$ sufficiently small such that whenever $|a - b| < \sqrt{2\pi} \delta$, $|f(t,x) - f(t,b)| < \frac{1}{\sqrt{8\pi}}\epsilon$. This implies that by Cauchy-Schwarz

$$ \int_0^{2\pi} |f(t,x) - f(t,\tilde{x})| |y| \mathrm{d}t \leq \left( \int_0^{2\pi} |f(t,x) - f(t,\tilde{x})|^2 \mathrm{d}t\right)\left(\int_0^{2\pi} |y|^2 \mathrm{d}t\right) \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2} \|y\|_E $$

Putting everything together we see that at a fixed $x$, for every $\epsilon > 0$, we can choose a $\delta > 0$ such that whenever $\|x - \tilde{x}\|_E < \delta$, the operator norm $\|\phi'(x) - \phi'(\tilde{x})\| \leq \epsilon$. Giving continuity.

---

The argument for $C^2$ is similar. Notice that for the $\int y'z'$ term the contribution to $\phi''(x) - \phi''(\tilde{x})$ is exactly 0. So we need to control

$$ \int_0^{2\pi} |f'(t,x) - f'(t,\tilde{x})| |yz| \mathrm{d}t $$

where $f' = \partial f / \partial_x$.

Again we fix $x$, and then if $\|\tilde{x} - x\|_E < \delta < 1$ we have that $f'$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,2\pi]\times [- \sqrt{2\pi}\ldots, \ldots] $. This gives that for every $\epsilon > 0$ we can choose $\delta$ sufficiently small such that $\sup_{t} |f'(t,x) - f'(t,\tilde{x})| < \epsilon$ whenever $|x(t) - \tilde{x}(t)| < \sqrt{2\pi}\delta$. For all such $\tilde{x}$ we then have

$$ \int_0^{2\pi} |f'(t,x) - f'(t,\tilde{x})| |y z| \mathrm{d}t \leq \epsilon \int_0^{2\pi} |y z|~\mathrm{d}t \leq \epsilon\|y\|_E \|z\|_E $$

by Cauchy-Schwarz, and this shows continuity.